# js is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the error message on a good way to solve? Error message: timetotal is not defined.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof(timeleft) !== 'undefined') {
        Chrono.update();
    }
    $('a.add_other_answer').click(function() {
        addAnswer();
    });
});

Chrono = {
    warning: timetotal * 0.25,
    critical: timetotal * 0.05,

    update: function() {
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: We need some more code, where is `timetotal` defined?

Comment: @Wolfy87: It seems it is not ;) @lander: You have to define `timetotal` somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty self-explanatory, even with your code example being incomplete.

`timetotal` is most likely undefined at this line, since it is passed as a property of the object `Chrono`:

```
warning: timetotal * 0.25,
```

You are most likely incrementing `timetotal` in your `Chrono.update` method, but that is too late: the property should have an initial value if you want to multiply it with `0.25` or `0.05`.

**Solution:**

```
var timetotal = 0;

Chrono = {
    warning: timetotal * 0.25,
    critical: timetotal * 0.05,
```

Comment: *Edit: I see you got it fixed...;)* *Edit2:* The last example won't work as `this` will not refer to `Chrono` but probably to `windows`. *Edit3:* This won't work either as `Chrono` is not defined yet when `Chrono.timetotal * 0.25` is executed ;) (there is no way to access a property of an object while defining another property).

Comment: @Felix noticed it before your comment and edited my post :) *edit*: fixed the second error as well now! Doh! :)

Comment: Please see the third edit in my comment ;) But +1 from me anyway :)

Comment: Haha clearly need another espresso. I'll just remove the second example alltogether and skip JS programming for the day. Thanks for the tips.